# Hibernate - native SQL + non-managed entities + collections

Tags: java, hibernate

[This documentation chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904) explains how to return non-managed entities for native queries. Is it possible for those entities to have collections of other non-managed entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory - yes. You can write your own result transformer (loosely based on  `org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer`) that would:

1. Use `transformTuple()` method to transform 'root' bean along with a single collection element.
2. Subsequently use `transformList()` to merge collection elements into matching parent beans.

In practice, however, it's *much* easier to actually map corresponding entities, even if you're only going to use it for retrieving the data from such a query.